# Additional fields for Ubercart uc_order_product

Tags: entities, hooks, ubercart

I need to add fields to the Ubercart entity uc_order_product. I was looking into the function field_create_instance, but don`t know exactly where to use it. I believe I should attach the field I want to the uc_order_product entity using field_create_instance.

The 'uc_order_product' definition in uc_order.module doesn't have a fieldable => TRUE definition. May I add that definition from my custom module and tell uc_order_product is fieldable? This is uc_order_product entity definition in the uc_order.module.

```
'uc_order_product' => array(
  'label' => t('Order product'),
  'base table' => 'uc_order_products',
  'controller class' => 'UcOrderProductController',
  'metadata controller class' => 'UcOrderProductMetadataController',
  'entity keys' => array(
    'id' => 'order_product_id',
    'label' => t('Order product'),
  ),
  'bundles' => array(
    'uc_order_product' => array(
      'label' => t('Order product'),
    ),
  ),
  'view modes' => array(
    'full' => array(
      'label' => t('Normal view'),
    ),
    'cart' => array(
      'label' => t('Cart view'),
    ),
  ),
  // Entity API callbacks.
  'access callback'   => 'uc_order_order_product_access',
  'save callback'     => 'uc_order_product_entity_save',
  'deletion callback' => 'uc_order_product_delete',
)
```

Finally, I am trying to hook to this entity when it gets updated (hook_entity_update, hook_entity_presave) but they never get called on uc_order_product update. How can I hook to this entity when it is being saved, or when it has been saved? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want alter the meta information of an entity, the `hook_entity_info_alter` in your custom module is the right way. More information in official page: [hook_entity_info_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7)

In this particular case, attributte 'fieldable' is not defined, so the function responsable to call the `hook_entity_info` and `hook_entity_info_alter` is the `entity_get_info()` in common.inc file. This function provide default values and the default value to 'fieldable' is `FALSE`. You only need change this value implementing `hook_entity_info_alter`.

```
 function YOUR_MODULE_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info){
   if(isset($entity_info['uc_order_product'])){
     $entity_info['uc_order_product']['fieldable'] = TRUE;
   }
 }
```

Second issue, [This is a link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8284/programmatically-create-fields-in-drupal-7/12939#12939) to a previous question about how create fields programatically. The best answer suggests `field_create_field`and 'field_create_instance', but if you have a defined field (for example, an image type field created through the UI), you could use `field_update_field` and 'field_update_instance'. You can find more information about these functions in field.crud.inc in the field module folder.