# Radio buttons widget for boolean field

Tags: nodes, entities

When I add new boolean field to content type in admin i can choose widget for it: checkbox or radio buttons. How can I describe it in code? When I do something like this there is no widget:

```
$i = 1; 
foreach($questions as $question){
        $field_name = $name . '_q' . $i;
        $fields[$field_name] = array(
            'field_name' => $field_name,
            'type' => 'list_boolean',
            'required' => true,
        );
        $i++;
}

foreach($fields as $field){
        if (!field_info_field($field['field_name'])) {
            field_info_cache_clear();
            field_create_field($field);
        }
}

$instances = array();

$i = 1;
foreach($questions as $question){
    $field_name = $name . '_q' . $i;
    $instances[$field_name] = array(
        'field_name' => $field_name,
        'label' => $question,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'radio'
         ),
         'required' => true
     );
     $i++;
}

foreach($instances as $instance){
    $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
    $instance['bundle'] = $name;
    field_create_instance($instance);
}
```

Comment: What does "describe it in code" mean?

Comment: I create content type and add fields for it in module.

Comment: What do you mean "no widget"? Field is there, appears in tpl.php and Views, but can't be edited by user?

Comment: There is a label for field but nothing else.

Comment: I found that for checkboxes i need to use widget type "options_onoff". But how to make it radios?

Comment: Maybe I'm using wrong field type? I just need to get an answer for the qustion when the new node of content type is created. Just "yes" or "now" with radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use [`field_create_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7) to create the field itself and [`field_create_instance($instance)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) to have an instance for your content type. Widget type should be set in `$instance['widget']['type']` sent to [`field_create_instance($instance)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7).

Taken from [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/8286/16495).

Comment: I do these things. It's not what I'm asking about. I can't figure out how to make my boolean fields look like radio buttons in form.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov if you are passing radio widget type to the field_create_instance(), please show relevant code. And if you want conditionally programmatically change widget (or not), please tell where / when you want to execute it and should this change be permanent or temporary.

Comment: I've added this code now.